# Trouble mapping over data - Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am saving some data (3 documents) into state.

I am receiving 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined' error when trying to map over an array in my react app.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong? 3 items should be mapped in the render function.

[image]

```
export default class Kim extends React.Component<IKimProps, IKimState> {

  public constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      documents: []
    }
    //SPComponentLoader.loadCss('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://hiddenforsecurityreasons.com/sites/KIM/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Id,Title,File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File",
              { params:{},
                headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
              })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          documents: response.data
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IKimProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.kim }>

        { setTimeout(function(){

          this.state.documents.d.results.map(document => {
            <li>{document.Title}</li> 
          })

        }, 6000) }


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Can you try to ```return``` the result of the map? It is an arrow function, but as you have braces it doesn't have implicit return, you have to write it

Comment: Can you please share the exact value of `response.data` ?

Comment: The answer has already been given as to why `this` is undefined, but also remember [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) returns the ID of the timer, so the list you are trying to print will never be rendered. Even if it did, you are not returning the result form your `map` function either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inside the timeout function, `this` is a reference to that function scope, not your React class scope, so `this.state` inside the timeout function is actually `undefined` because there's no `state` inside the function, so when your code tries to read `documents`, it can't because you cannot get `documents` from undefined, as it states.

You can remove your timeout and add an if check around your `map` call instead.

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IKimProps> {
    return (
        <div className={ styles.kim }>
            {this.state.documents.length? this.state.documents.d.results.map(document => <li>{document.Title}</li> ) : null } 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Another way of dealing with `this` while keeping your timeout function is to use arrow functions.

> While in ES5 ‘this’ referred to the parent of the function, in ES6,
>   arrow functions use lexical scoping — ‘this’ refers to it’s current
>   surrounding scope and no further. [read more here](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881#.59q9th108)

Comment: `setTimeout` will not return the results even when scoped correctly with an arrow function. It returns the ID of the created timer.

Comment: @BrianThompson makes a good point actually, you should not use the setTimeout expecting it to return your JSX.

Answer (score 0):

try arrow function, for sure it is a problem with this

```
{ setTimeout(() => {

      this.state.documents.d.results.map(document => {
        <li>{document.Title}</li> 
      })

    }, 6000) }
```